# Hang a 100lb heavy bag from ceiling

Tags: ceiling

I'm trying to figure out the safest way to hang a 100lb heavy bag from the ceiling in my garage.

The pictured part is under a bedroom, and the continuous line, if it's like the part that is under the attic has a 1.5inch wide piece of wood.  The other half of the garage does not have any of the perpendicular beams.

From what I've read, I can't just hang it with a single eye bolt, and I don't have access to the other side because of the room above.  I found this [TuffRail](http://www.tuffrail.com/overhead.php) system, but I'm not convinced that it would be structurally sound.  I also found this [SpiderMount](https://www.firstlawfitness.com/products/spider-mount-punching-bag-mounts?variant=34298475463), but the spacing of the larger beams doesn't match.

Is it possible to safely hang the bag?

Attached is a picture[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So a 100lb bag getting rocked by punches may be disturbing to whoever is upstairs it's not all that heavy for the structure. A single drywall sheet is around 50 pounds or so(not going to google exact weight). So the issue is fastening to the ceiling. I like the second one you posted because of the springs. I would fasten some light duty metal square tubing across the span of the joists in such a way that I could bolt the spider mount to the metal.

Hand drawn (obviously) conceptual illustration
[image]

With this method you can run the tubing across several joists spreading the load so over time they won't sag.

I think your joists run this way and in the method outlined above the metal tube would run perpendicular to the joists spanning 3 joists for redundancy. 
[image]

Comment: What do you mean by "across the span of the joists"?  Is that the "short" or "long" lines in my image?

Comment: It's hard to say but I'm leaning towards the long lines and in the short lines you should find screws peaking out of plaster. The short lines should not be the direction of the joists there should be 3 screws in each short line. Every screw will be a joist running parallel to the long lines. In garages they often get the rookie crews to drywall and plaster so it's really hard say for sure. A stud finder can help alot. Also the usual 16" centers often don't apply in garage ceilings because they are often lowered to add a insulating space. They often get the rookie framers to do that too.

Comment: The shorter lines were as described with 2 or 3 screws in each one.  When hanging things from the ceiling is it always recommended to go through 3 joists, or is 2 ok sometimes?